# How is JQuery available inside of a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with a template that is coded using jquery 1.8.2 and porting over some scripts that were built with jquery 3x.  So the error I am dealing with right now is derived from this:

```
function validateForm(formElem){
     $(formElem).find('input, checkbox, textarea').each(function(){});
}
```

Errors with

```
TypeError: $ is not a function
at formValidate (form.min.js?cache=1:3)
at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> ((index):165)
at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
at HTMLFormElement.h (jquery.min.js:2)
```

I guess I'm not sure how this code ever worked because as I understood it, jquery normally got loaded into the global scope and thus would not be available inside a function. Yet it does work with jquery 3 and I don't know how to make it work with jQuery 1.8x

I tried doing stuff like :

```
window.$ = window.jQuery;
```

or

```
var $ = jQuery;
```

directly after loading the jquery script (inside head tags) but it didn't make a difference.  I would rather not rewrite all my scripts to the old usage format if possible. Would someone be able to explain how jQuery 3 works inside a function and how do I get 1.8 to run from $ inside a function as well.

Comment: The code you've provided would not fail due to a jQuery version update. Perhaps there's a conflict. Are you loading multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?

Comment: Variables available in the global scope are available in all narrower scopes. That's why they're "global".

Comment: Have you tried `jQuery(formElem)...`? Also, are you sure jQuery is actually loaded at the time your function is fired?

Comment: I had this error when declaring code before link Jquery

Comment: Expanding on my initial comment: Are you sure that when you changed the URL to the new version of jQuery, that it's still resolving properly? In the developer console, are there any 404s? If not, in the Network tab, do you see *multiple* versions of jQuery being retrieved? Are you sure that you're including jQuery **before** the rest of your JavaScript?

Comment: You would get that error if JQuery library is not linked on page.

Comment: Please provide more details about how the scripts are being loaded. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Ok, that make sense about variable scope.  When I read about it seemed like functions where isolated from global vars.  I confirmed the jquery is getting loaded only once successfully, in the proper location.  I think this has something to do with how I am calling the function :

jQuery(document).ready(function($){$("#form-adXoFAv0").submit(function(event){formValidate(this);});});

I'm going dig in that now

Comment: Turns out that one of the plugins was calling noConflict().  Thanks for all your help.